# Cannot import CanvasJS in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, canvasjs

CanvasJS do not possess a npm package so you have to download it manually to use it locally.
So, I did it, added *canvasjs.min.js* to my project and import it in my component. But it doesn't work :

```
  ERROR in src/app/survey/survey.component.ts:8:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/assets/canvasjs.min.js'.

  import * as CanvasJS from 'src/assets/canvasjs.min.js';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my tree folder :

```
- src
 -- app
  --- survey
  ---- survey.component.ts
 -- assets 
  --- canvasjs.min.js
```

In my component I included the library like this :

```
import * as CanvasJS from 'src/assets/canvasjs.min.js';
```

And here is my jsons configuration all at my project root :
**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
 {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**extract from angular.json**

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-httpclient-example": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-httpclient-example",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          }
```

I already tried :

- Add the path in scripts of angular.json
- Move .js everywhere in any folder possible
- Change my path with absolute and relative paths
- Change baseUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to import it in your `angular.json` in the *scripts* section.

```
"scripts": [
  .....
  "/assets/canvasjs.min.js"
]
```

Now you should be able to declare canvas js as `any` and your good to go.

```
declare const CanvasJS: any;

...
export class MyClass {
   public chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      ....
}
```

Comment: I have this error : An unhandled exception occurred: Script file /assets/canvasjs.min.js does not exist.

Comment: 1. You could check if the file is actually located under `/src/assets/`
2. Check spelling of filename

Comment: I used intellj features to create the path to be sure it's well located and named. I changed library and it works fine with a other one so I gave up with canvas.. thank you